# T-SQL variable show Incorrect syntax near '@tableName'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

It shows an error ,when try to run this

```
declare  @tableName VARCHAR(250)

select @tableName='['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'

FROM sys.tables
WHERE '['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'='[Management].[Table_1]'

print @tableName

TRUNCATE table @tableName
```

Incorrect syntax near '@tableName'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct.  You cannot use variables to pass table names.

You *can* use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = replace('TRUNCATE table @tableName', '@tableName', @tableName);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

SQL statements are allowed to have parameters for *constants*, but not for identifiers.  This is not only a SQL Server limitation, but a limitation in all (?) databases.  Dynamic sql is often used for this purpose.

[TSQL sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @user1254579 . . . That is how SQL is defined.  In the case of SQL Server, there is a conflict with a table variable and a table name.  To be honest, if the variable were set at compile time, I don't see an issue with it -- but no database supports this.